# Hazelcast near cache - huge get latency

Tags: caching, hazelcast

There are 3 objects stored in my map - couple of MB each. They don't change so it makes sense to cache them locally at the node. And that's what I thought I was doing before I realized the average get latency is huge and that slows down my computations by large. See that hazelcast console:

[image: Hazelcast console view]

This makes my wonder where did it get from. Is it those 90 and 48 misses which I think  happend at first? The computations are run in parallel so I figure they could all issue a reguest to get before the entries were even cached and thus all of those would not benefit from near-cache at this point. Is it then some pre-loading method so that I would run it before I trigger all those parallel tasks? Btw. why entry memory is 0 even if there are entries in that near cache data table?

Here is my map config:

```
<map name="commons">

        <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>

        <backup-count>0</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
        <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>

        <near-cache>

            <in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>
            <max-size>0</max-size>
            <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
            <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
            <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
            <invalidate-on-change>true</invalidate-on-change>
            <cache-local-entries>true</cache-local-entries>
        </near-cache>
    </map>
```

*The actual question is why there are so many misses in the near cache and is it where that huge average get latency may come from?*

Comment: I'm actually not sure I got the question but the entry memory is 0 because you use "In-Memory-Object::Object" which means we cannot calculate the memory consumption. Could you rephrase the actual question?

Comment: Are you using clients or just these 2 servers ? If the latter, have you tried `backup-count` set to 1 and `read-from-backup` set to true.

Comment: I'm using multiple servers and a single client application. A client application doesn't fetch those values more than once (to set them). I cannot really use backup-count as node count can vary and this value cannot be set to more than 6...

Answer (score 2):

The latency that management center shows, is the latency after a request hit the server. If you have a Near Cache and you hit Near Cache, that will not show on the Man.Center. I suspect that you shall not be observing the high latency from your application. I see that there have been 34 events. I assume this entry have been updated. When an entry is updated, it is evicted from Near Cache. The subsequent read will hit the server.

Comment: Two entries are never updated from the beginning whereas one is added in the middle of the run but also never changed. While it makes sense what you said still, why so many misses?

Comment: It is really hard to say from a distance.